# JS diagram library

Tags: library, javascript, diagram

I'm looking for a javascript library, that can draw diagrams like this:
[image]

Requiments:

1. Basics, draw boxes with labels
2. Links ("relationships") between two boxes
3. Multiple ports for a box, where links starts/points to
4. Smart link routing: they shouldn't go under/above a box
5. Links should not overlap each other. In the image below, the right side is what I need.
   [image]

Optional:

- Grouping items
- Able to customize link crosses (if the link routing is good, that "jump over" feature shown on the first image isn't needed)

Joint or GoJS is similar to what I need, but they don't support the 5th requiment.

Comment: Should the user be able to drag the nodes, while the connectors auto-follow?