# Angular or JS components to build and visualize graphs

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, graphs, diagram, angular

I am looking for recommendations on Angular or JS (whatever license) components to (1) build and (2) visualize graphs

[Tomsawyer's Graph database browser](https://www.tomsawyer.com/graph-database-browser/) is a good example, but it's a solution, not a component we can use in a project,

Also not looking for embeddable libraries like Cytoscape.js, D3.js, Vis.js, or Sigma.js. but for a component, something like ag-grid, but for graphs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS diagram library](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/38605/js-diagram-library)